# Schema validation in WSO2 API manager version 3.0 against openAPI specification

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, json-schema-validator

I am new to WSO2. We are trying to implement WSO2 api manager for our project. So I have downloaded wso2 api manager 3.0 and started to explore it. In that I have seen schema validation option and then referred the documentation of it. According to that I have added schema definition in my API as per Open API specification (v3.0). But after enabling the schema definition, it doesn't seem to validate the request against the schema defined. Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Please provide any any information related to this.

JSON schema validation in WSO2 api manager 3.0 documentation:
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/APISecurity/APIRequestResponseSchemaValidation/json-schema-validator/

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided a valid request payload/parameters or if the response you get is according to the schema you have provided you won't get any special notifications to indicate that the values have passed through the schema validation. If the req/response payload does not adhere to the schema, then you will get the error message.

Did you get any error message? Also, share your OpenAPI schema definition to see whether that has some issues.